# Reloading UITableView - how does it check if the data's changed?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I was having trouble reloading a UITableView today.

For debugging purposes I had my model classes' return the description of its NSDictionary instance variable. And as my CellIdentifier I used this description to make sure I always have current data while developing. Maybe a very stupid and ineffective way to handle reusing UITableViewCells, but that's just the way I did it earlier.

Anyhow. I was wondering why after reloading my data the UITableView wasn't refreshing at all, not even after reloadData, needsLayout *and* needsDisplay. The data was good and exchanged for the new one, but it wasn't rendered like that.

After some time of debugging I found out that the problem got away when removing my custom description method, so the default value (pointer description, memory position?) was used.

Now my question is: why is that? I assume that UITableView checks for the data's description having changed. When returning a fixed value with the description method I could perfectly reproduce the problem. So I am right, the description method is what's being used to determine if data's got to be reloaded, right?

Well, here's a second part of my question: I stupidly returned the description of a contained, huge NSDictionary, right. But that dictionary *had* to be different after reloading, too. Now I'm wondering - is there another way UITableView tries to find out there's a difference? Or is it just the ultra-long description being cut off after n characters anyway? The difference (a value changed from "6" to "7") occurred quite late in the description, after maybe 500 characters or something like that …

Thanks for your info :)

Arne

Comment: It would be helpful to see you implementation of - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath